# Paint method is not working

Tags: java, paint

I'm trying to make a 2D game that should draw a character to the screen. But when I run it, I just get a black screen.

The important bits:

```
public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Walrus walrus;
    private Image image, character;
    private Graphics second;
    private URL base;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);

        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Applet");
        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        // Image Setups
        character = getImage(base, "src/data/walrus_right.png");

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        walrus = new Walrus();

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            walrus.update();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            second = image.getGraphics();
        }

        second.setColor(getBackground());
        second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        second.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(second);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);     
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(character, walrus.getCenterX() - 61, walrus.getCenterY() - 63, this);

    }
}
```

Also, here's my other class:

```
public class Walrus {

private int centerX = 100;
private int centerY = 382;
private boolean jumped = false;

private int speedX = 0;
private int speedY = 1;


public void update() {

    // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.
    if (speedX < 0) {
        centerX += speedX;
    } else if (speedX == 0) {
        System.out.println("Do not scroll the background.");

    } else {
        if (centerX <= 150) {
            centerX += speedX;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Scroll Background Here");
        }
    }

    // Updates Y Position

    if (centerY + speedY >= 382) {
        centerY = 382;
    }else{                        
                    centerY += speedY;
            }

    // Handles Jumping
    if (jumped == true) {
        speedY += 1;

        if (centerY + speedY >= 382) {
            centerY = 382;
            speedY = 0;
            jumped = false;
        }

    }

    // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
    if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
        centerX = 61;
    }
}

public void moveRight() {
    speedX = 6;
}

public void moveLeft() {
    speedX = -6;
}

public void stop() {
    speedX = 0;
}

public void jump() {
    if (jumped == false) {
        speedY = -15;
        jumped = true;
    }

}

public int getCenterX() {
    return centerX;
}

public int getCenterY() {
    return centerY;
}

public boolean isJumped() {
    return jumped;
}

public int getSpeedX() {
    return speedX;
}

public int getSpeedY() {
    return speedY;
}

public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
    this.centerX = centerX;
}

public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
    this.centerY = centerY;
}

public void setJumped(boolean jumped) {
    this.jumped = jumped;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
    this.speedY = speedY;
}
```

}

I haven't gotten any errors at this point, but it's not working right.

Comment: Why do you use `Frame` (AWT) instead of `JFrame` (Swing)?

Comment: Also: (1) we can't run your code because we don't have `Walrus`. We probably don't need it either - post a minimal and runnable code; (2) You seem to block the EDT with `sleep`, create a new thread for it instead.

Comment: I added the walrus class to my post. The reason for all those things is probably because I was following [this tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/game-development-tutorial.html).

Comment: That tutorial looks like it's meant for Android, while you are using applets and other AWT components which won't work on Android. Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your image is not loaded. The line

```
getImage(base, "src/data/walrus_right.png");
```

tries to read the image for a *deployed applet* and will fail quietly (not throw errors), which is what caused the confusion. Try to replace it with

```
ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("relative/path.png").getPath()));
```

where you should replace the path as specified under [`getResource` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

**Edit:**

Break the call into several calls:

```
Class<? extends StartingClass> clas = getClass();
URL url = clas.getResource("relative/path.png");
String path = url.getPath();
File file = new File(path);
try {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and move with the debugger step by step to see which line throws the error. My guess is that the file is not located in the right place, which causes `getResource` to return `null`, which causes `new File(path)` to throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think I'm not doing this right. I replaced that line with   `ImageIO.read(newFile(getClass().getResource("relative/data/walrus_right.png").getPath()));` , and I now get a null pointer exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pack.StartingClass.init(StartingClass.java:38)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)` Also, when I use JFRames rather than Frames, I get a different error, something about not being able to cast Applet to JFrame.

Comment: @Charizard See my edit about treating the exception.